# ransack exact match of keyword search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

how to use **ransack gem in rails** for exact match of search keyword instead of partial search?

for example -

If I search for keyword "formers", it should not search for "Transformers" etc, instead serach for only "formers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `eq` predicate: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching#eq-equals

i.e. If you're searching the `first_name` field, then your form field would be `first_name_eq`